# Is this a bug or feature? im not sure

Tags: generics, typescript

not sure, is should post this here, but this is place where i landed...

error messages in comments are shown at lines bellow them. Why these errors are shown? Specially error #1 because T extends ITest so it should be safe cast...

```
interface ITest {
    answer?: number; // error #1 dissapears if '?' is removed
}

class Base<T> {
    obj: T;
}

class Derived<T extends ITest> extends Base<T> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        var obj = { answer: 42 };

        // ok ... no suprise here
        var test:ITest = obj as ITest;

        // #1 Neither type { answer: number } or type T is assignable to each other.
        var t:T = obj as T;

        // this works ... (why? - specially when 1. dont...)
        var t2:T = obj as ITest as T;

        // #2 Type { answer: number } is not assignable to type 'T'.
        // #3 Cannot convert type { answer: number } to type T. Type parameter T is incompatible with { answer: number }, with is not type parameter.
        this.obj = obj;

        // #4 Type ITest is not assignable to type 'T'.
        // #5 Cannot convert type ITest to type T. Type parameter T is incompatible with ITest, with is not type parameter.
        this.obj = test;

        // this works
        this.obj = obj as any;

        // in this case error is not shown even if 'answer' is required in ITest ... 
        // (expected: 'Type { totally: string } is not assignable to type 'T'.)
        this.obj = { totally: 'different' } as any;
    }
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all of those errors come from two issues, but before we get to them you need to understand how typescript compares types, and that's [using duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#introduction) ([more on duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type-checking focuses on
>   the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or
>   “structural subtyping”

In your code you do this:

```
var obj = { answer: 42 };
```

Here `obj` isn't an `ITest`, its' type is `{ answer: number }`, and the compiler will match that to `ITest` when it can, but that doesn't make `obj` to be of type `ITest`.
If you want it to be `ITest` you need to do:

```
var obj = { answer: 42 } as ITest;
```

Or

```
var obj: ITest = { answer: 42 };
```

If you define `obj` to be `ITest` then error #1 is gone (with or without the optional property), which is also why you don't get an error here:

```
var t2: T = obj as ITest as T;
```

The rest of your errors are due to the fact that `T` isn't `ITest`, it extends it.
For example if I have:

```
interface ITest2 extends ITest {
    question: string;
}

let c = new Derived<ITest2>();
```

Then now this:

```
var obj: ITest = { answer: 42 };
...
this.obj = obj;
```

Is problematic, as `obj` is of type `ITest` but `this.obj` needs to be of type `ITest2`.

You can tell the compiler to trust that you know what you're doing:

```
this.obj = obj as T;
this.obj = test as T;
```

([your code with no error in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ITest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20answer%3F%3A%20number%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20%231%20dissapears%20if%20'%3F'%20is%20removed%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Derived%3CT%20extends%20ITest%3E%20extends%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20obj%3A%20ITest%20%3D%20%7B%20answer%3A%2042%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ok%20...%20no%20suprise%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20test%3A%20ITest%20%3D%20obj%20as%20ITest%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%231%20Neither%20type%20%7B%20answer%3A%20number%20%7D%20or%20type%20T%20is%20assignable%20to%20each%20other.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20t%3A%20T%20%3D%20obj%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20works%20...%20(why%3F%20-%20specially%20when%201.%20dont...)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20t2%3AT%20%3D%20obj%20as%20ITest%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%232%20Type%20%7B%20answer%3A%20number%20%7D%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%233%20Cannot%20convert%20type%20%7B%20answer%3A%20number%20%7D%20to%20type%20T.%20Type%20parameter%20T%20is%20incompatible%20with%20%7B%20answer%3A%20number%20%7D%2C%20with%20is%20not%20type%20parameter.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj%20%3D%20obj%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%234%20Type%20ITest%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%235%20Cannot%20convert%20type%20ITest%20to%20type%20T.%20Type%20parameter%20T%20is%20incompatible%20with%20ITest%2C%20with%20is%20not%20type%20parameter.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj%20%3D%20test%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20works%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj%20%3D%20obj%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20in%20this%20case%20error%20is%20not%20shown%20even%20if%20'answer'%20is%20required%20in%20ITest%20...%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20(expected%3A%20'Type%20%7B%20totally%3A%20string%20%7D%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T'.)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.obj%20%3D%20%7B%20totally%3A%20'different'%20%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

When you cast to `any` then you basically tell the compiler not to type check, so that's why you don't get an error for:

```
this.obj = { totally: 'different' } as any;
```